# How would I create an Array class that can have lower bounds other than zero (in C++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

This is what I have so far.  It throws an exception when I try to access an index out of bounds.  I tried to say "return NULL" if the range is out of bounds for the overloaded subscript operator, but it's not working.  The problem is when I try to assign a value to an index above the upper limit it allows it to happen.  Like with the current code if I change the "< 8" in the main function to "< 9", it uses array element 8 without problem, but I want it to have a problem with that.  Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

//L for lower-bound, U for upper-bound
template <typename T, int L, int U>
class LBArray
{
    public:
      LBArray()
      {
        lbound = L;
        ubound = U;
        data = new T[ubound - lbound];
      }
      T& operator[](int index)
      {
        if (index < lbound || index > ubound)
        {
          throw out_of_range("index out of bounds");
        }
        return data[index - lbound];
      }
      ~LBArray()
      {
        if (data) delete[] data;
      }
    private:
      T *data;
      int lbound;
      int ubound;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  LBArray<int, 5, 7> data;
  cout << "LBArray<int, 5, 7> data\n";
  for (int x = 5; x < 8; x++)
  {
    data[x] = x;
    cout << endl << "data[" << x << "] = " << data[x];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider `LBArray<int, 0, 5>`. The constructor allocates an array of 5 elements. Then trying to access element 5 passes the range check and goes out of bounds. Also, since you're using a pointer for whatever reason, ensure you follow the Rule of Three/Five, and that check in the destructor isn't necessary. Finally, ensure that you can access elements in a `const` object as well.

Comment: Just a tip, you don't need `lbound` and `ubound`. You can use `L` and `U` directly (of course, preferably after you give them more meaningful names c:)

Comment: Why not just wrap a `std::vector` instead of doing manual memory management?  That would be much easier.

Comment: rule of zero is better than rule of five. I am a fervent activist against the rules of N when N is not zero. http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html

Comment: I didn't understand your problem, I changed the 8 in the main for loop to 9 and when it try to access the 8th index it throws an exception as you should expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create array from 5 to 7, and I suppose that 5 and 7 included, then you have 3 elements data[5], data[6], data[7], but in your code:

```
data = new T[ubound - lbound];
```

and that 2 elements 7-5 = 2. You lose one element.
Therefore I think you need do like that:

```
data = new T[ubound - lbound + 1];
```

After that change all work fine, but you do not use try..catch, then your code shutdown.
If you do not want to use try..catch, I offer to you next code:

```
T& operator[](int index)
{
    if (index < lbound || index > ubound)
    {
        T nullVar = NULL;

        return (T&)nullVar;
    }
    return data[index - lbound];
}
```

Attempting to get element with wrong index the function return NULL.

Comment: I took your advice on that, but I am still having a lot of issues.  It is not creating the proper number of elements in the array.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that uses std::vector as the underlying container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, size_t L, size_t U>
class LBArray
{
   std::vector<T> data;
   void checkIndex(size_t index) 
   { 
        if ( index < L || index >= U )
            throw out_of_range("index out of bounds");
   }

public:
    LBArray() : data(U - L) {}
    T& operator[](size_t index)
    {
       checkIndex(index);
       return data[index - L];
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        checkIndex(index);
        return data[index - L];
    }
};

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    LBArray<int, 5, 7> data;
    cout << "LBArray<int, 5, 7> data\n";
    for (int x = 5; x < 8; x++)
    {
        data[x] = x;
        cout << endl << "data[" << x << "] = " << data[x];
    }
}
```

Note that the `operator[]` is overloaded for both const and non-const access.  Also, the LBArray class can now be safely copied since the `std::vector` does the memory management.