# How do you properly set and get passed-in array bounds in a template (in C++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to create an array of typename T, so it can be ints or doubles or anything.  Then I went to make it where 0 isn't the lowest bound - that you can set whatever lowest bound and upper bound you want.  The problem with this code I find is in the main function.  It should not be printing out values outside of the range I put it in, but it always does. For this code it should be making 12 - 5 + 1 = 8 elements, but indexes 1 through 12 are accessible and shouldn't be.  Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//L for lower-bound, U for upper-bound
template <typename T, int L, int U>
class LBArray
{
    public:
      LBArray()
      {
      data = new T[U - L + 1];
      }
      T& operator[](int index)
      {
        return data[index];
      }
    private:
      T* data;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  LBArray<int, 5, 12> data1;
  for (int x = 1; x < 13; x++)
  {
    data1[x] = x;
    cout << endl << "data1[" << x << "] = " << data1[x];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not mapping the `index` argument of `operator[]` to the appropriate range. And also decide what you want to happen when they access outside this range.

Comment: `for (int x = 1; x < 13; x++)` indexing of c++ arrays starts at `0`.

Comment: Looks like this poor `new` has lost his `delete` buddy :(

Comment: Please see your other post here, plus an implementation using `vector` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772348/how-would-i-create-an-array-class-that-can-have-lower-bounds-other-than-zero-in#comment38440650_24772348

Comment: "indexes 1 through 12 are accessible" - no they're not. Indexes more than 6 are out of range, and give undefined behaviour if you access them. If you want a run-time check that an index is in range, you have to supply it yourself - C++ doesn't do that automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing too much work. One thing at a time; one class should do one thing and one thing only. Don't conflate resource management and index computations. Just make a class to handle your index offsetting, and leave the memory management to someone else:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t L, std::size_t U>
struct OffsetArray
{
    static_assert(L < U, "Bad bounds");

    static std::size_t const lower_bound = L;
    static std::size_t const upper_bound = U;

    T data[upper_bound - lower_bound];

    T & operator[](std::size_t i) noexcept
    { return data[i - lower_bound]; }

    T const & operator[](std::size_t i) const noexcept
    { return data[i - lower_bound]; }

    std::size_t size() const noexcept
    { return upper_bound - lower_bound; }

    // ...
};
```

Usage:

```
OffsetArray<int, 5, 13> x;
x[5] = 10;
```

If you need dynamic containers, you can always stick the array into `std::vector` or some such.